# How to install YAML::PP perl module by resolving this error?

Tags: fedora, perl-module, kdevelop

I constantly keep getting this error while trying to compile Kdevelop on my Fedora 27 virtualbox.
As mentioned in [here](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source), I try to use this line `kdesrc-build kdevelop`

And I get this response:

```
kdesrc-build requires some minimal support to operate, including support from the Perl runtime that kdesrc-build is built upon.

Some mandatory Perl modules are missing, and kdesrc-build cannot operate
without them.  Please ensure these modules are installed and available to Perl:
one of (YAML::XS, YAML::PP, YAML::Syck)
```

So I try to install using `cpan YAML::PP`
And I get this test summary report :

```
t/32.cyclic-refs.t      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=20, Tests=1198,  9 wallclock secs ( 0.29 usr  0.03 sys +  3.93 cusr  0.48 csys =  4.73 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/20 test programs. 0/1198 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:945: test_dynamic] Error 255
  TINITA/YAML-PP-0.006.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (Test::Warn); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports TINITA/YAML-PP-0.006.tar.gz
```

[This](https://notepad.pw/5fygqx11) is the whole error I get (Since I can't upload it here due to character limitations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install some perl modules using `dnf`. So for this problem you could do `sudo dnf install perl-YAML-Syck` (yaml::syck is one of the modules that it says will work above).

Alternatively, to avoid this problem entirely, you can just install kdevelop without compiling it, if you want, using `sudo dnf install kdevelop`.